# Fine tuning a Deep Learning model post training

Tags: deep-learning, fine-tuning, imbalanced-datasets

I have trained a CNN in a binary classification problem, however the original problem has 6 different classes, of which, I am only interested in classifying one, so if it is that certain class or not.in this case, let's say class 2.

After looking closely into the model's performance on test dataset, I have found that the model confuses class 2 with class 1 often. Is it common practice, to make a balanced dataset from the data that I have only from class 1 and class 2, and further train the model on that dataset? Are there any pieces of research/papers on this? If no, what other possible solutions would there be, of course other than making a new model?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the technique of **Transfer Learning** to fine-tune your model. You can take the weights from the pre-trained model and then use them as initializations for your own model.

Yes!, It is common practice to make a balanced dataset when training a machine learning model, as this can help prevent the model from **overfitting** to one class or the other. A model trained on a balanced dataset would be more accurate at predicting the classes.

In your case, if you have more data from `class 1` than `class 2`, you may want to downsample the `class 1` data so that both classes are represented equally. You can then train your model on this balanced dataset and see if it improves performance on the test set.

There is a great deal of research has been conducted on the topic of data balancing and its impact on machine learning models. few papers on the topic include

- [On the effectiveness of preprocessing methods when dealing with different levels of class imbalance](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220392058_On_the_effectiveness_of_preprocessing_methods_when_dealing_with_different_levels_of_class_imbalance)
- [Learning from Imbalanced Data](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Learning-from-Imbalanced-Data-He-Garcia/6a97303b92477d95d1e6acf7b443ebe19a6beb60)
- [A review on data preprocessing methods for class imbalance problem](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/336305785_A_review_on_data_preprocessing_methods_for_class_imbalance_problem)